# How do I send ESC/POS to a receipt printer using Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, point-of-sale, epson

I would like to print a receipt on an Epson thermal receipt printer using ESC/POS.

The printer is connected by USB and there is a printer driver installed. But I do not want to print a generated raster image. Instead I want to send the raw ESC/POS commands to the printer.

ESC/POS is basically plain text with some escaped commands that allow some additional formatting, cut the paper and even open a cash drawer that is connected to the printer. I've already created a Windows version of my application in C# and already know how to format the data that has to be send to the printer. For all intents and purposes of this question, assume that I have a buffer with valid ESC/POS commands that need to be send to the printer.

C# does not allow me to open a printer directly and write raw data to it, so I basically P/Invoke some functions from the Win32 API.

The code looks like this:

```
    public Boolean Print(string printerName, byte[] document)
    {
        try
        {
            NativeMethods.DOC_INFO_1 documentInfo;
            IntPtr printerHandle;

            documentInfo = new NativeMethods.DOC_INFO_1();
            documentInfo.pDataType = "RAW";
            documentInfo.pDocName = "POS receipt";

            printerHandle = new IntPtr(0);

            if (NativeMethods.OpenPrinter(printerName.Normalize(), out printerHandle, IntPtr.Zero))
            {
                if (NativeMethods.StartDocPrinter(printerHandle, 1, documentInfo))
                {
                    int bytesWritten;
                    byte[] managedData;
                    IntPtr unmanagedData;

                    managedData = document;
                    unmanagedData = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(managedData.Length);
                    Marshal.Copy(managedData, 0, unmanagedData, managedData.Length);

                    if (NativeMethods.StartPagePrinter(printerHandle))
                    {
                        NativeMethods.WritePrinter(
                            printerHandle,
                            unmanagedData,
                            managedData.Length,
                            out bytesWritten);
                        NativeMethods.EndPagePrinter(printerHandle);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw new Win32Exception();
                    }

                    Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(unmanagedData);

                    NativeMethods.EndDocPrinter(printerHandle);
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Win32Exception();
                }

                NativeMethods.ClosePrinter(printerHandle);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Win32Exception();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
    }
```

The `Print()` command takes the name of the printer and an array of bytes as parameters. The purpose is to open the printer that is named and send the array of bytes as raw data.

I hope there is a solution that uses the printer driver in one way or another, because that abstracts the way the printer is connected. The printer I currently have for testing is connected using USB, but there are also models that have a serial port and can be connected using a Serial to USB cable.

**My question:**
How would I do the equivalent of the code above in Objective-C?

Comment: Get the I/O Registry Explorer.  (I don't recall whether it's included with Xcode or a separate download.). In the explorer, find the printer (you'll have to connect it to the mac of course). Copy the device details from the explorer and paste them into your question.

Comment: @robmayoff I'll add the data from the I/O registry explorer, but I'd rather not directly speak on the USB level. I'm hoping for a solution that involves the printer driver in some way, because that abstracts the method in which the printer is connected.

The printer I'm dealing with now is connected by USB, but the same model could also be connected using a serial port on the printer and a serial to USB adapter. Or by ethernet using TCP/IP.

Comment: Did you find out a way to send ESC/POS commands to the printer ..? I need to send cash drawer open command. I've find out the set of character codes but don't know how to implement them in Objective-C.